# How to capture binary process output in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, streaming

I want to launch an external application, and capture its output.
That's pretty easy, using  `Diagnostics.Process` and its `OutputStream`.

However, the process I have generated **binary** data, which I need to capture as a `Stream`, not as the textual `StreamWriter`

Its there a way to get the underlying raw binary stream?

Currently, I hack it by launching a batch file which looks like:

`myapplication | socat stdin tcp-connect:localhost:12345`

And in my code I create and listen on a TCP socket. while this hack works, its a bit ugly, and I prefer to use the external process directly.

(One thing I *can't* do is use local files, as the data is real-time in its nature)

Answer (score 4):

How about [`p.StandardOutput.BaseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.basestream.aspx)?

Comment: How about to give a full answer?

Comment: @SerG: This is a full answer.  The only question asked was "Its [sic] there a way to get the underlying raw binary stream?"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named pipe, similar to but more in-depth than the OutputStream functionality of Process (which is basically a listener for StandardOutput). Named pipes are accessible using Streams, without any assumption as to the content being Unicode character data. They also don't tie up network ports, unless you want to connect to a pipe remotely (which is also possible).

Comment: But you need to modify the child process to make it use the pipe, or else p/invoke `CreateProcess` to pass the pipe as the child's standard output handle.

Answer (score 1):

I used the follwowing code to read binary data from stdout of a program

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "yourProcess";
info.Arguments = "blah";
info.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("latin1");//important part
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
FileStream fs = new FileStream("outputfile.bin", FileMode.Create);

while((val = p.StandardOutput.Read())!= -1){
    fs.WriteByte((byte)val);
}

p.WaitForExit();
fs.Close();
```